# How do elements of $\mathbb{R}(xy,x+y)$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have problems with determining what are typical elements of such field $\mathbb{R}(xy,x+y)$

In one indeterminate it is easier as

$\mathbb{R}(x)=\Bigl\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}, g(x)\neq 0, f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\Bigr\} $

where

$f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\dots+a_{n}x^{n}$

$g(x)={b_{0}+b_{1}x+b_{2}x^2+\dots+b_{n}x^{n}}$

and by translating the above case, we get something like this

$\mathbb{R}(xy,x+y)=\Bigl\{\frac{f(xy,x+y)}{g(xy,x+y)}, g(xy,x+y)\neq 0, f(xy,x+y),g(xy,x+y)\in\mathbb{R}[xy,x+y]\Bigr\} $

but does $f(xy,x+y)$ really mean? Can we take for example

$f(xy,x+y)=5xy-3(x+y)$?

Can someone give me example of non trivial elements belonging to the above field?
For example is it true that  $(xy)^2=x^2y^2\in \mathbb{R}(xy,x+y) $?

Comment: You need to define what $\mathbb{R}(xy, x+y)$ really is. Is it the field of fractions in two indeterminates, called for some reason "$xy$" and "$x+y$"? Is it the subfield of $\mathbb{R}(x,y)$ generated by $xy$ and $x+y$?

Answer (score 4):

This is the field of all rational functions symmetric in $x$ and $y$. So for example it contains
$x^3+y^3+5x^2y+5xy^2 -x-y$ since this is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

$x+y$ and $xy$ are the elementary symmetric functions and a basic theorem of algebra is the every symmetric rational functions is a rational function of the elementary symmetric functions.

Comment: Dear Rene: You wrote: "This is the *field* of all *polynomials* symmetric in x and y". But there is no such *field*. The polynomials symmetric in x and y form a *ring*.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard oh sorry I meant rational functions.

Comment: Great answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can "build these up". Notice that $\mathbb{R}(xy,x+y) = \mathbb{R}(xy)(x+y)$.

This is similar to $\mathbb{R}(x+y)$ but instead of having coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, the coefficients are in $\mathbb{R}(xy)$.